# nhibernate returns an empty collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a scenerio where I am saving a graph of objects and I need to retrieve it later on in another process. Simple case of data manupulation really.

The problem is that after a successful save of the object and its associated collection- as indicated by the output insert statements- a subsequent query for the same object returns an empty collection for its associated collection. I even call Flush() before that. Strangely, closing and reopening the application makes it return the populated collection.

I have this mapping for the Appointment class

```
<set name="workhours" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="true">
  <key>
    <column name="person" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="workhour" />
</set>
```

Here's the code for data retrieval

```
Method1()
{
 DataAccessManager.StartOperation();
        IEnumerable<Entity> q = GetQueryProvider();
        if (total > 0)
        {
            q = q.Skip(startIndex).Take(total);
        }
        totalfound = q.Count();
        IList<Entity> list = q.ToList();
        DataAccessManager.EndOperation();
        return list;
}
protected override IEnumerable<Entity> GetQueryProvider()
    {
        return DataAccessManager.GetQueryProvider<Appointment>();
    }
```

and this is for saving

```
        if (this.Patient.Appointments== null)
            this.Patient.Appointments= new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<Appointment>();
        this.Patient.Appointments.Add(this);

        if (this.Doctor.Appointments== null)
            this.Doctor.Appointments= new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<Appointment>();
        this.Doctor.Appoint.Add(this);
        Entity ent = base.Save();
        return ent;

      //the base call:
      DataAccessManager.StartOperation();

        try
        {
            Entity t = DataAccessManager.Save<Entity>(this);
            DataAccessManager.EndOperation();
            return t;
        }
        catch (NHibernate.HibernateException ex)
        {
            //handling            }

//the Data Access save method

 public T Save<T>(T t) where T : Entity
    {

        try
        {

            CurrentSession.SaveOrUpdate(t);

            return t;
  }
 ///exception handling and stuff
  }
```

I end the session with a Commit() and Disconnect() .

Answer (score 0):

Never mind it, I wasn't setting associations before saving.